# Django DRF: how to groupby on a foreign fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model where users can upvote other users for specific topics. Something like:

```py
#models.py
Class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.StringField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

Class UserUpvotes(models.Model):
    """Holds total upvotes by user and topic"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    topic= models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    upvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Using DRF, I have an API that returns the following: `topic_id`, `topic_name`, and `upvotes`, which is the total upvotes for a given topic.

> One of the project requirements is for the API to use these field names specifically: `topic_id`, `topic_name`, and `upvotes`

```py
#serializers.py
class TopicUpvotesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topic_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source="topic")

    class Meta:
        model = UserUpvotes
        fields = ["topic_id", "topic_name", "upvotes"]
```

My trouble is aggregating these fields. I'm filtering the `UserUpvotes` by user or team and then aggregating by topic.

### Desired output

This is the result I want to get. When I *don't* perform any aggregations (and there are views where this will be the case), it works.

```json
[
    {
        "topic_id": 3,
        "topic_name": "Korean Studies",
        "upvotes": 14
    },
    {
        "topic_id": 12,
        "topic_name": "Inflation",
        "upvotes": 3
    },
]
```

At first, I tried creating a `TopicSerializer`, and then assigning it to the `topic` field in `TopicUpvotesSerializer`. But then, the resulting json would have a nested "topic" field and the aggragation would fail.

### Attempt 1

```py
#views.py

def get_queryset(self):
    return (
      UserUpvotes.objects.filter(user__team=team)
          .values("topic")
          .annotate(upvotes=models.Sum("upvotes"))
          .order_by("-upvotes")
      )
```

My problem is that the `topic_id` and `topic_name` fields are not showing. I get something like:

```json
[
    {
        "topic_name": "3",
        "upvotes": 14
    },
    {
        "topic_name": "12",
        "upvotes": 3
    },
]
```

### Attempt 2

Another queryset attempt:

```py
# views.py

def get_queryset(self):
    return (
      UserUpvotes.objects.filter(user__team=team)
          .values("topic__id", "topic__name")
          .annotate(upvotes=models.Sum("upvotes"))
          .order_by("-upvotes")
      )
```

Which yields:

```json
[
    {
        "upvotes": 14
    },
    {
        "upvotes": 3
    },
]
```

The aggregation worked on the queryset level, but the serializer failed to find the correct fields.

### Attempt 3

This was the closest I got:

```py
# views.py

def get_queryset(self):
    return (
      UserUpvotes.objects.filter(user__team=team)
          .values("topic__id", "topic__name")
          .annotate(upvotes=models.Sum("upvotes"))
          .values("topic_id", "topic", "upvotes")
          .order_by("-upvotes")[:n]
      )
```

```json
[
    {
        "topic_name": 3,
        "topic_name": "3",
        "upvotes": 14
    },
    {
        "topic_name": 12,
        "topic_name": "12",
        "upvotes": 3
    },
]
```

I have no idea why "topic_name" is simply transforming the "topic_id" into a string, instead of calling the string method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with a serializer for the topic:

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    upvotes = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'upvotes']
```

then in the `ModelViewSet`, you annotate:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class TopicViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TopicSerializer
    queryset = Topic.objects.annotate(upvotes=Sum('userupvotes__upvotes'))
```

Comment: Because I had to change the name from id -> topic_id and name -> topic_name, it became a bit verbose, but it works for this aggregation scenario. 

That setup will break things in my Users API, herwever. There, I have the field "upvoted_posts" receiving `TopicUpvotesSerializer`. Regardless, your answer is correct for the question as I put it  ;-)

(sorry for not saying how else that serialize was being used)

Answer (score 0):

> Desired output
> This is the result I want to get. When I don't perform any aggregations (and there are views where this will be the case), it works.

```
[
    {
        "topic_name": 3,
        "topic_name": "Korean Studies",
        "upvotes": 14
    },
    {
        "topic_name": 12,
        "topic_name": "Inflation",
        "upvotes": 3
    },
]
```

The serialized FK will always give you the `ID` of the related model. I am not sure why you name it `topic_name` if that is equal to an `ID`. Now, if you really want to get the `name` field of the `Topic` model
in the  `topic_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source="topic")` you should give it a `source="topic.name"`

However, if you trying to get the ID of the relation you can still use  `ModelSerializer` :

```py
class TopicUpvotesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserUpvotes
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: That was a typo (I don't want 2 topic_name fields). Changing to `source="topic.name"` by itself didn't solve it for me. I still got only the `topic_id` and `upvotes` field.

Changing the serializer to `fields= "__all__"` will give me a KeyError on the `user` field, which is expected as I don't want that field in the output.

Answer (score 0):

[@willem-van-onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem)'s answer is the correct one for the problem as I had put it.

But... I had another use case (sorry! ◑﹏◐), for when the Users API used `UserUpvotes` serializer as a nested field. So I had to find another solution. This is was I eventually ended up with. I'm posting in case it helps anyone.

class UserUpvotesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
topic_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
def get_topic_name (self, obj):
    try:
        _topic_name  = obj.topic.name
    except TypeError:
        _topic_name = obj.get("skill__name", None)
    return _topic_name

class Meta:
    model = UserUpvotes
    fields = ["topic_id", "topic_name", "upvotes"]
```

I still have *no idea* why the `SerializerMethodField` works and the `StringRelatedField` field doesn't. It *feels* like a bug?

Anyways, the rub here is that, after the `values().annotate()` aggregation, `obj` is no longer a QuerySet, but a dict. So accessing `name`directly will give you a 'UserUpvotes' object is not subscriptable error.

I don’t know if there are any other edge cases I should be aware of (this is when I REALLY miss type hints in Django), but it works so far